# How to overcome greedy match everything when looking for a particular string later?

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

```
echo "A number is about to show up 1 and now I want to parse 365 guys and some extra junk"  | sed -E 's/.*([0-9]+) guys.*/\1/g'
```

The above command currently outputs just `5`. Essentially I'd like to parse the number of "guys" in a random sentence that could have numbers (or not.. I'd also like to parse just `echo "365 guys"`) preceding the number of guys. My `.*` is matching the `36` and preventing it from appearing in the `\1`. How can I write a sed command (or any other regex/perl/awk) to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the "frugal" quantifier `*?` in Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/.*?([0-9]+) guys.*/$1/'
```

Comment: There's no reason for `.*` to be there at all

Comment: @Borodin: There is, you want to replace it. Of course there are other ways how to approach the problem.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't spotted that this was a substitution

Comment: I would also offer perlishly `perl -lne 'm/(\d+) guys/ and print $1'`

Answer (score 2):

With ***GNU* `grep`**:

```
$ grep -Po '\b[0-9]+(?= guys\b)' <<<"365 guys or 366 guys, but not foo12 guys."
365
366
```

- `-P` actives support for [PCREs](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcre.html), which enables advanced regex features.
- `-o` specifies that only the matching parts of input lines should be printed.
- `\b` matches only on a word boundary, including at the start of a line;
  this prevents matching numbers that aren't stand-alone numbers but part of other words, such as in `foo365 guys`, and words that *start* with `guys`, such as `guysanddolls`.
- `(?= guys)` is a look-ahead assertion that matches the enclosed subexpression without including it in the matched string returned.

As demonstrated, this may match *multiple* patterns on a given line, with each number extracted printed on its own output line.
If that is undesired, `grep` cannot be used, because `-o` *invariably* returns all of a line's matches; see the `perl` command below for a solution.

---

Inspired by [Sobrique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2566198/sobrique)'s comment on choroba's answer, here is the **`perl` equivalent** of the above `grep` command:

```
$ perl -lne 'print for m/\b(\d+) guys\b/g' <<<"365 guys or 366 guys, but not foo12 guys."
365
366
```

Simply omit the `g` to only match at most *1* number per line.

Answer (score 1):

Since your number is preceded by a blank, you can make it a part of the regex:

```
echo "A number is about to show up 1 and now I want to parse 365 guys and some extra junk"  | sed -E 's/.* ([0-9]+) guys.*/\1/g'

# => 365
```

Comment: great suggestion, but my sentence might not always be preceding by the space. echo "365 guys and some extra junk" is also a valid input. I'll make the question more robust. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

In Bash:

```
$ s="A number is about to show up 1 and now I want to parse 365 guys and some extra junk"
$ [[ $s =~ ([0-9]+)\ +guys.*$ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
365
```

Or, with awk:

```
$ echo "$s" | awk '/guys/{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="guys" && $(i-1)+0==$(i-1)) print $(i-1)}'
365
```

Answer (score 0):

with standard `sed` regex you can benefit from greedy match if you reverse the string and matching

```
echo ... | rev | sed -E 's/.*syug ([0-9]+).*/\1/g' | rev
```

obviously this is a hack, but desperate times...

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew Cassidy: @try:

```
   echo "A number is about to show up 1 and now I want to parse 365 guys and some extra junk"  |
awk '/guys/{print VAL;exit} {VAL=$0}' RS=" "
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -r 's/.*\b([0-9]+) guys.*/\1/' file
```

or perhaps:

```
 sed -r 's/.*\<([0-9]+) guys.*/\1/' file
```

Make the numeric part of the pattern match a word boundary.